# Бездействия телефона(30-45 секунд) на первом запуске Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase

Добрый день всем, такой вопрос, есть приложение, при первом запуске приложения, еще не загружается первое активити, а телефон весит белый экран , делает какие-то операции, в логах вообще ничего нету на этот момент, куда копать ???? 
пользуюсь Android Studio, накручен на проект firebase файл вложен.

Comment: Вы использовали многопоточность для firebase и операций с бд?Или же всё закинули в главный поток - и в нем все выполняете?

Comment: Многопоточность не использую, это происходит еще до события onCreate,  еще к firebase я не подключился. я вот предполагаю, что это может быть из-за вложенного файла ? он может делает какие-то скрытые запросы в firebase, если так то как его в потом отдельный пустить тоже вопрос?

Comment: думаю, вы не понимаете работу вашего приложения, отсюда и все проблемы, скиньте код, который затрагивает этот файл и firebase - тут никто не телепат.

Comment: Так или иначе без многопоточности оно постоянно будет вести себя тормознуто и с лагами.

Comment: Сталкивался с такой проблемой, решено было отключением Instant Run в Android Studio.

Comment: Андрей, а с чем это вообще связано ?

Comment: Instant Run позволяет мгновенно перезагружать активити с изменениями без пересборки всего приложения. При использовании сторонних решений типа firebase или как  в моем случае ActiveAndroid сборка приложения выполнялась криво и приводило к длительному старту.

Comment: Андрей, а как отключить это ?

Comment: Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run
Убрать все галочки

Comment: Андрей,у меня заблокированы все чекбоксы, у вас такое было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воообщем я погуглил и нашел кое какую инфу, у меня в ЛОгаг было это 
бла бла бла бла 
07-27 21:41:47.834 30750-30750/com.vvv.logicpix D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user
бла бла бла, как я и предполагал, файл который мы генерировали что бы добавить в проект, он сам конектится к фаербейс без нашего ведама. я очень много гугл проблему и наткнулся на то что, есть такая проблема сейчас все о ней говорят. это проблема на стороне гугл.фаер бейс. впервые с 14 июля 2016 года она была замечена и по сей день 27 07 2016 не исправлена, первоисточник 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742361/android-firebase-auth-state-listener-called-multiple-times